# How to show and hide <div>'s in Popover using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on `SPA` (Single Page Application) for Online Team Collaboration service(OTC) ,and I include `HTML` pages by `ng-include`,in some included page there is a `popover` ,this one contains a possibility for creating a public group chat,and in order to create one ,the user must submit, now my question is : how can i display a "successfully created" message in the same popover instead of the main div for creating the group in the popover?

The `external page` (the page that include other pages):

```
<div ng-show="ctrChanneldiv" ng-contoller="ctrChannelCon" style="float: right;" class="col-md-3">
    <div ng-include="'CreateChannel.html'" ></div>
</div>
```

The Controller `ctrChannelCon`:

```
appvar.controller('ctrChannelCon',['$scope','$http','$rootScope',function($scope, $http, $rootScope){
        $scope.createBtn = function() {
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/ExampleServletv3/crtchannelservlet",this.crtchannel)
                    .success(function(response) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $scope.$apply(function(){
                                //******* Here Display "Successfully Created" In the Popover *******//
                            });
                        });

                    });
           };
      }]);
```

In `CreateChannel.html` :

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <a href="#" class="popper" data-toggle="popover"
            data-placement="bottom"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Create Channel</a>
        <div class="popper-content hide">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- ng-controller="createChannelCon" -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Channel name:</label>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input ng-model="crtchannel.Name" type="text" placeholder="enter channel's name" maxlength="30"
                       class="form-control input-md" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea cols="15" ng-model="crtchannel.Description" type="text"
                          placeholder="enter channel's description" maxlength="500"
                          class="form-control input-md" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input ng-model="crtchannel.Type" type="radio" name="chtype"
                       value="private" required /> Private<br> <input
                       ng-model="crtchannel.Type" type="radio" name="chtype"
                       value="public" /> Public<br>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button ng-click="createBtn()" class="btn btn primary">Apply</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.popper').popover({
            container : 'body',
            html : true,
            content : function() {
                return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [**ngClass**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive to counter this problem. ngClass directive allows conditional application of classes. Create a div for successfully created in the popup and set up ng-class directive with a variable in the scope and assign it true and false as per your requirement.

**JS**

```
appvar.controller('ctrChannelCon',['$scope','$http','$rootScope',function($scope, $http, $rootScope){
        $scope.createBtn = function() {
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/ExampleServletv3/crtchannelservlet",this.crtchannel)
                    .success(function(response) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $scope.$apply(function(){
                                //******* Change value of a model *******//
                                $scope.hidden = false;
                            });
                        });

                    });
        };
    }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<span ng-class="{hide: hidden}">Successfully Created</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag in your controller on success and use this flag to show or hide the success message:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <button ng-click="createBtn()" class="btn btn primary">Apply</button>
</div>
<div ng-show="isSuccess">Successfully Created</div>
```

Inside the controller:

```
$scope.isSuccess = false;
$scope.createBtn = function() {
        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/ExampleServletv3/crtchannelservlet",this.crtchannel)
                .success(function(response) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $scope.$apply(function(){
                            //******* Here Display "Successfully Created" In the Popover *******//
                            $scope.isSuccess = true;
                        });
                    });

                });
       };
```